# FileSavePicker Contract Implmentation

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, windows-8, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I have implemented the FileSavePicker Contract in my app,so when user selects an attachment from mail app and want to save to my app ,then OnTargetFileRequested(FileSavePickerUI^ sender, TargetFileRequestedEventArgs^ e) method gets triggered....

```
OnTargetFileRequested(FileSavePickerUI^ sender, TargetFileRequestedEventArgs^ e) 
{
auto request = e->Request;
auto deferral = request->GetDeferral();

create_task(ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync(sender->FileName,    CreationCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName)).then([request, deferral](StorageFile^ file)
{
    // Assign the resulting file to the targetFile property indicates success
    request->TargetFile = file;

    // Complete the deferral to let the Picker know the request is finished.
    deferral->Complete();

return file;

 }.then([=](StorageFile^ file)

{

 //here i will upload file to my metro app 

}
```

now whatever file i was created that i need to upload to my metro app....but i am facing an issue with deferral->complete...whether deferral->complete() complete need to written after uploading the file to my app or above the deferral->complete statement is correct.??...

but when i use deferral->complete after uploading the file always 0 bytes of file is getting uploaded...

if i use deferral->complete in createFileAsync() as shown in above code then the file is not getting uploaded........please help me...

can you tell me is this the correct approach?..

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should call the deferral->Complete() after the last await call in your method - the purpose of defferal is to inform the caller, that even the called method returned, there is still async action in progress. Once deferral is called complete, then the caller knows everything was done.

So you should probably call the deferral->Complete() after uploading the file or after copying the file to your cache. If no bytes are transfered, make sure you transfer the file correctly - you have to open the original file using OpenReadAsync and copy the stream to either your memory stream (not recommended for large files), or to cache file or somewhere and then send it.